# Big O Notation and Adding functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $f$ is $O(h)$, is $(f-g)$ still $O(h)$, regardless whether $g$ is $O(h)$ or not ?

Comment: $g$ could be any function at all, so $f-g$ could be any function at all.

Comment: Are you saying that $f−g$ , for any g is $O(h)$

Comment: I am saying the opposite. .... $ f(x)=O(h(x))$ as $x\to \infty$  iff there exists $K\in \Bbb R^+$ such that $|f(x)|\leq K|h(x)|$  for all sufficiently large $x$...... Now let  $j$ be any function and let $g=f-j.$ Then $f-g=j.$ And it is not possible for every $j$ to be   $O(h)$. For example for $n\in \Bbb N$ and $x\in [n,n+1)$ let $j(x)=n+nh(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Countereexample:

Suppose $f(x)=x$, hence it is $O(x)$ and $g(x)=x^2$.

Check that $f-g$ is not $O(x)$.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that $x-x^2 \leq cx$? Doesnt this hold for $x,c \geq 1$

Comment: I think you left out absolute value in the definition of big O notation.

Comment: Yes, then the statement won't hold.